# Plotting graph using matplotlib python

Tags: python, networkx, traveling-salesman

I need to plot the graph for the following solution of the ACO TSP. The graph that I need to plot would be something close to this:

[image: ACO TSP Graph]

Any code snippets on which I could work on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of [tsplib95](https://tsplib95.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/usage.html#loading-problems):

> ```
> Converting problems
> get_graph() creates a networkx.Graph instance from the problem data:
>
> >>> G = problem.get_graph()
> >>> G.nodes
> NodeView((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16))
> ```

So, G is a `networkx` graph, which means you can use `networkx` to draw it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

nx.draw_networkx(G)
plt.show()
```

edit: drawing the path:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

H = nx.DiGraph(G) # convert to directed graph s.t. the edges have arrows. 

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(H, pos=pos) # draw nodes
nx.draw_networkx_edges(H, pos=pos, alpha=0.1) # draw all edges with transparency
nx.draw_networkx_edges(H, pos=pos, edgelist=tour.path, edge_color='red') # highlight the edges in the path

plt.show()
```

Comment: Is it possible to then draw the tour, which is the finished version of G (having the algorithm applied to G to get the shortest distance)?

Comment: probably. can you try type(tour) to see what datatype the tour has?

Comment: The tour is of class 'acopy.solvers.Solution' . I can also get the tour nodes and path using tour.nodes and tour.path.

Comment: The code seems to work, but no graph is being outputted

Comment: what are you working in? try plt.show() at the end

Comment: Okay the graph is outputted now. Is there a way to make it look like I posted in the question? if not, this should suffice

Comment: meaning you just want the edges of the optimal graph? I updated the answer; you can remove the line that draws all edges, and just draw the optimal path.

Comment: Yes optimally I just get the edges. This looks better. I had to remove the with_labels since it was giving me an error. Thanks!

Comment: yes, correct. I removed this from the answer.